# CSS, display property(menuBar)

Tags: html, css, inline, block

I am trying to understand html/css menu bar and my problem is at the display property,

I do know about this property very well, but if you take a look at this [Link](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/matt_black_tabs/),
just a simple menubar, but the problem is that i dont understand why does the li tag and the a tag at the css style include display property inside them when the float do the job and you can delete them and the menu looks the same, i know that there is a resone for thoes display properies to be there at thoes both tags styles but i dont get it, if can some one please help me understand why the display property with the value of inline at the li css style, and with value of block at the li a at the css style, and again its not that i dont know about this property it just i dont understand why its there, thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display:inline` used in li's is to make li aligned Horizontal or side by side.

`display:block` is used in li a so the a should take the complete with of the li so that if you click anywhere inside li the `<a>` tag will work & will not only work on clicking on the text.

Comment: thank you for your answer, at the li you said aligned vertical or side by side, when you saying "or" what do you mean becouse vertical is vertical and side by side sounds like horizontal, but i know that inline should set them as horizontal but i didnt understand why set the horizontal when the float does the job, i does understand what do you say about the display:block but if you take a look at the the code inside the link above you can see that the link is taking the all with even if you delete the display:block, ill be happy if you can help me here, and thanks again.

Comment: ohh!! extremely sorry its horizontal. And if u remove display:block its taking the width & height because of padding. If u just remove display:block & padding both & give some height & width to li the the a will work only for text portion. And i am really sorry for that mistake i am correcting it now. Its 12:30 AM here & i am sleepy. But Stackoverflow is addictive.

Comment: its ok you should never be sorry its happens we human, anyway thank you again, i did understand why there is a display:block at the a thank you, but i didn't understand why there is display inline at the li, ill be happy if you can please help me with that, thank you again and good evening.

Comment: display:inline is used to make li's aligned horizontally if, we will not make this inline the default property of li is applied which is block(li are block elements) & all li's will be vertically aligned in this case. I know still works if i remove display inline, this is because <a> is made display:block & floated left so its making all a aligned horizontally.

Comment: Thank you again i got it now, but can you tell me what should i do when i know that i dont really need to use them, i mean i know i gonna run into lots of css and see that some part of the code are not necessary, do you think the display is there to "Match" the standart so the validation at W3C will pass, ill be happy to listen to your opinion, and thanks again.

Comment: Its just to make it working. Its not used to pass any w3c validation. Different ppl write different css to do the same work, so the developer of this plugin used it differently or forgot to remove that display:inline coz as i said there is no use of display:inline there as <a> is already floated & working as a block element.

Comment: thank you again, do you think i should remove the display from the li and from the a becouse the float do the job?